# scala method isAnonymousClass returning false

Tags: scala

I have defined a anonymous class using new{ ... } but when i try to print the isAnonymousClass instead of returing true it's return false what's wrong here

```
scala> trait An{}
defined trait An

scala> val isAn = new An{}
isAn: An = $anon$1@2731370f

scala> println(isAn.getClass.isAnonymousClass)
false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code sample:

```
package scala.tools.nsc
package interpreter

import scala.reflect.{ ClassTag, classTag }

class RichClass[T](val clazz: Class[T]) {
  def toTag: ClassTag[T] = ClassTag[T](clazz)

  // Sadly isAnonymousClass does not return true for scala anonymous
  // classes because our naming scheme is not doing well against the
  // jvm's many assumptions.
  def isScalaAnonymous = (
    try clazz.isAnonymousClass || (clazz.getName contains "$anon$")
    catch { case _: java.lang.InternalError => false }  // good ol' "Malformed class name"
  )
```

Edit:

It seems obvious that you'd want to fall back on the Scala name test if `isAnonymousClass` throws.

It's not trivial to tweak the name test, except to eliminate the enclosing class, which seems safe.

```
  def isAnon(k: Class[_]) = {
    def klass = k.getEnclosingClass.getName
    val encl  = Option(k.getEnclosingMethod) orElse Option(k.getEnclosingConstructor)
    encl map (_ => k.getName drop klass.length match {
      case "" => true
      //case r  => (r dropWhile (_ == '$')).startsWith("anon$")  // nope
      case r  => List("$anon$", "$anonfun$") exists (r contains _)
    }) getOrElse false
  }
```

The enclosing class (as reported by `getEnclosingClass`) is not always correct:

```
  Console println isAnon {
    object X { class Y; def y = new Y { class Z ; def z = new Z() } } ; X.y.z.getClass
  }
```

The named class Z, or `isanon.Test$X$9$$anon$4$Z` is enclosed by the object `isanon.Test$X$9$` and not by the anonymous subclass of Y.

In this case, `$anon$4` is the encloser and `Z` is the named inner class.

It might be possible to work around that by detecting the pattern, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Scala [bug raised](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2749) about this but it's been closed, so it seems unlikely that this will be fixed as you'd like it to work any time soon.

In the meantime, you can use inspection of the class name as suggested by @som-snytt, or (and I'm bracing for downvote-oblivion here) you *might* be able to use `isLocalClass` instead?
Note the difference here:

```
scala> trait An
defined trait An

scala> val isAn = new An {}
isAn: An = $anon$1@2f1c5a78

scala> class Bn extends An
defined class Bn

scala> val notAn = new Bn
notAn: Bn = Bn@50734372

scala> isAn.getClass.isLocalClass
res3: Boolean = true

scala> notAn.getClass.isLocalClass
res4: Boolean = false
```

Comment: The bug is in how generated names are encoded, cf https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2034 and `isLocalClass` also does a name test. Downvote means "not useful"; an answer can be wrong but still useful.